# I am not able to access this filename [{"filename":"54526108_1946746692102415_4003062236024143872_n.jpg"}]

Tags: node.js

I have tried console.log(filename.filename); but it is not working.

[{"filename":"54526108_1946746692102415_4003062236024143872_n.jpg"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s an array with an object in it. Just try

```
console.log(filename[0].filename)
```

Comment: showing undefined

Comment: Ok, can you add your code in the question?